# Custom HTTP Status Codes with Google Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to return an 'unsupported' HTTP 4xx status code using a subclass of endpoints.ServiceException?

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions **first** seems to say that it's not possible

> Only the HTTP 4xx codes listed below are supported... Use of other HTTP 4xx codes will result in an HTTP 404 response.

**But then** just a little later says that it is?

> If you want to create other exception classes for other HTTP status codes, you can do so by subclassing endpoints.ServiceException. The following snippet shows how to create an exception class that represents an HTTP 409 status code...

If I work  their snippet into my application I don't seem to be successful -- is this that it isn't possible or simply that I've made an error when using the suggested snippet for custom exception class use?

My Python file:

```
# Standard library imports import httplib

# 3rd party imports import endpoints from protorpc import messages from protorpc import message_types from protorpc import remote


package = 'Unprocessable'


class UnprocessableEntityException(endpoints.ServiceException):
    """Unprocessable Entity exception that is mapped to a 422 response."""
    http_status = httplib.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY


class ACustomMessage(messages.Message):
    """Greeting that stores a message."""
    important_field = messages.StringField(1)


def process_important_field(important_field):
    a = important_field * 1

@endpoints.api(name='main', version='v1') class UnprocesableTestHandler(remote.Service):
    """ This class handles the creation of entities from a user for storage in
    the data store.
    """

    @endpoints.method(
        ACustomMessage, ACustomMessage, path='test', 
        http_method='POST', name='test.notprocessable'
    )
    def test_improcessable(self, request):
        important_field=request.important_field

        try:
            process_important_field(important_field)
        except TypeError:
            raise UnprocessableEntityException()

        return ACustomMessage(important_field=important_field)

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([UnprocesableTestHandler])
```

And the associated YAML:

```
application: unprocessable
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.APPLICATION

libraries:
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

With valid input sent in the POST request the above is great, but if I alter the POST data to contain the field "i_field" rather than "important_field" then I get a 503 back rather than the expected 422 and the following in the console.

```
ERROR    2014-06-11 15:29:08,686 service.py:191] Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: KeyError (422)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1329, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Users/saffy/Desktop/422Example/main.py", line 43, in test_improcessable
    raise UnprocessableEntityException()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_exceptions.py", line 31, in __init__
    httplib.responses[self.http_status])
KeyError: 422
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says these are the only 404 codes you can map to:

> 400
>   401
>   403
>   404
>   405
>   408
>   409
>   410
>   412
>   413

So 422 is out of this range.

The default ones are:

> endpoints.BadRequestException HTTP 400
>   endpoints.UnauthorizedException    HTTP 401
>   endpoints.ForbiddenException   HTTP 403
>   endpoints.NotFoundException    HTTP 404

Try mapping your exception to 405-413

Comment: OK - So my new understanding of the documentation is that the documentation for creating other exception classes is correct, but can ONLY be used for 4xx codes in the ranges 400-405, 408-410 and 412-413. That's clearer, thanks.